# Can you edit class files added to gradle in Android?

Tags: java, android, gradle

My app uses a Java library from jitpack.io, which I have added to my `build.gradle` file like this:

```
repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
        compile 'com.thejava.library'
}
```

Is it possible to edit a file within this library on my development machine? I suppose the files are cached or saved somewhere on my machine but I cannot find them, I suspect there might be hidden or protected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to edit a file within this library on my development machine?

Not readily. The code will be compiled.

However, since most stuff up on jitpack is open source, you might consider finding the open source project that is the source of the library. You can then fork and modify that library, using it as a library module in your app.